# How to populate table with array in jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a problem I can't figure out. I have an ajax success function that loops through a multidimensional array like so:

```
function onSuccessClientCustomerData(data) {
    // Count length of object
    var count = 0;
    for (i in data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            count++;
        }
    }

    // Fetch data
    var arr = new Array(data.variable0, data.variable1, data.variable2, data.variable3, data.variable4);
    for(var i = 0; i< count; i++) {
        var variable = $.parseJSON(arr[i]);

    }
}
```

I each arrays have three keys and I want to populate the td:eq(1) to td:eq(2) on each row:

```
<table id="test">
<tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
<td class="outputName">-</td>
    <td class="outputRating">-</td>
<td class="outputTurnover">-</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
<td class="outputName">-</td>
    <td class="outputRating">-</td>
<td class="outputTurnover">-</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

How do I do that. I've tried som each functions but couldn't get it to work!

Would be grateful for any help or references to read!

Thanks!

**EDIT / HERE IS MY SOLUTION**

```
function onSuccessClientCustomerData(data) {
    // Count length of object
    var count = 0;
    for (i in data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            count++;
        }
    }

    // Fetch data
    var arr = new Array(data.variable0, data.variable1, data.variable2, data.variable3, data.variable4);
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        var arr_j = $.parseJSON(arr[i]);
        $("#row" + i + " .key0").html(arr_j.name);
        $("#row" + i + " .key1").html(arr_j.rating);
        $("#row" + i + " .key2").html(arr_j.percentOfTotalIncome);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need help in the part where you have to insert the values? If so:

## jQuery Code

```
function onSuccessClientCustomerData(data) {
    // Count length of object
    var count = 0;
    for (i in data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            count++;
        }
    }

    // Fetch data
    var arr_i = new Array(data.variable0, data.variable1, data.variable2, data.variable3, data.variable4);
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        var arr_j = arr_i[i];
        for (var j = 0; j < arr_j. length; j++) {
            $("#row" + i + " .key" + j).html(arr_j[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

## HTML Code

```
<table id="test">
  <tr id="row0">
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td class="key0" class="outputName">...</td>
    <td class="key1" class="outputRating">...</td>
    <td class="key2" class="outputTurnover">...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row1">
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td class="key0" class="outputName">...</td>
    <td class="key1" class="outputRating">...</td>
    <td class="key2" class="outputTurnover">...</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

## Test Code

I tested the code with Chrome and it worked fine. Here are the steps to reproduce it:-

- Open the Elements pane using <kbd>F12</kbd> and do the following:

  1. Add the HTML part to a webpage;
  2. Optionally add a border and some margins to make it clearer;

- Open the Web Console using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> and do the following:

  1. Give `arr_i` (we'll be using that instead of `data`) a placeholder value:

     ```
     var arr_i = new Array([00, 01, 02], [10, 12, 13]);
     ```
  2. Run the code to set `count`:

     ```
     // Count length of object
             var count = 0;
             for (i in data) {
                 if (data.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                     count++;
                 }
            }
     ```
  3. Use my function to add the values (be sure to run the code on a page that uses jQuery! Or else, use [this bookmark](http://marklets.com/jQuerify.aspx)):

     ```
     for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
         var arr_j = arr_i[i];
         for (var j = 0; j < arr_j. length; j++) {
             $("#row" + i + " .key" + j).html(arr_j[j]);
         }
     }
     ```

And voilà! This should probably fetch me about 20 to 30 votes <del>by today</del> <del>tomorrow</del> <del>this week</del> next year (hopefully) ...

Comment: Will try when I get to me my computer! Thanks!

Comment: Hey tested it now, I get this out {, ", 0 so this means it doesn't fetch the key values. Only the three first characters. Don't know why?!

Comment: Your suggestions works but I have a multidimensional array so the $.parseJSON() is needed. I tried adding it to your suggestion but that doesn't work :) At least not for me :)

Comment: I tweeeked your code some but it works perfectly! Thank you! :)

Comment: @Ismailp Happy to help. Would you mind editing my answer to reflect the tweaks you made? It'll help future readers and I'd like to see it... *:)*

Comment: @Ismailp You sure about trying to cut, paste and format code on an iPhone? (BTW, which one?)

Comment: Ohhh, you meant you're on your iPhone right now and you'll update the code later...

Comment: BTW, will you believe I've practically _no_ knowledge of JS or jQuery? All of this os drawn on my Python experiences and the docs...

Answer (score 0):

```
function onSuccessClientCustomerData(data) {
    var data = $.parseJSON(data);
    ....
}
```

You need to parse the data first.

Comment: Look at the success function. It is already parsed. I get the data but I want to know how to populate the table as described